# Examine for overlap in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

Let's say I have the following start and end days/times:

[image]  `SHEET1`

Resulting in a range of time from `Mon 10am through Tues at 11:59pm`.

I'd like to know whether this range of time overlaps another range of time on a separate sheet.

Below is an example of 2 date ranges to compare to: one that overlaps and one that doesn't:

[image] `SHEET2`

I'd like the function in the row associated with `OVERLAP?` to return either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether there is overlap in the given time range with the range shown for `SHEET1`.

**Is it possible to construct date ranges based on start/end times and then compare that range to other ranges of time to determine if there's overlap?**

- Preferably all on the fly (i.e., not saving any outputs to a sheet until the final `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

**Sample Sheet** (as comma delimited):

```
Start Day,  Monday, 
Start Time, 10:00 AM,   
End Day,    Tuesday,
End Time,   11:59 PM

Day of interest,    Monday,     Tuesday,
DOI start,          8:00 AM,    8:00 AM,
DOI end,            9:00 AM,    9:00 AM,    
OVERLAP?,           FALSE,      TRUE
```

Comment: are also these data typed in or calculated by formulas?

Comment: @user0 should all be typed in

Comment: updated question to include comma delimited data. thanks

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

the spreadsheet doesn't understand the "advanced" human logic from a go like connections between events and comparing the overlap of their durations... therefore **`Sheet1!B1`** needs to be converted into date format corresponding to same day (in present, past or future - reference doesn't matter) with appended time from **`Sheet1!B2`** which is then compared to **`Sheet2!B1`** with appended **`Sheet2!B2`** etc.

simply said, formula does this:

**`if`** **<kbd>Monday 8:00 AM</kbd>** **`>`** or **`=`** to **<kbd>Monday 10:00 AM</kbd>** **`and`** **<kbd>Monday 9:00 AM</kbd>** **`<`** than **<kbd>Tuesday 11:59 PM</kbd>** statement is **`TRUE`** otherwise its **`FALSE`** like in this case

```
=AND(IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 1; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 1; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 2; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 2; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 3; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 3; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 4; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 4; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 5; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 5; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 6; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 6; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 7; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 7; 1); )))))))&B2 >=
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 1; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 1; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 2; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 2; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 3; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 3; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 4; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 4; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 5; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 5; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 6; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 6; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$1=TEXT(DATE(2018; 7; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 7; 1); )))))))&Sheet1!$B$2; 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 1; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 1; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 2; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 2; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 3; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 3; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 4; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 4; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 5; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 5; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 6; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 6; 1); 
     IF(B1         =TEXT(DATE(2018; 7; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 7; 1); )))))))&B3 <
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 1; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 1; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 2; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 2; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 3; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 3; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 4; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 4; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 5; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 5; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 6; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 6; 1); 
     IF(Sheet1!$B$3=TEXT(DATE(2018; 7; 1); "dddd"); DATE(2018; 7; 1); )))))))&Sheet1!$B$4)
```

paste this formula to **`Sheet2!B4`** and drag it over to **`Sheet!C4`** cell

[image]

Comment: Phew!! I've got to slowly digest this one! That's quite the function..